# Merge of two enums zod

Tags: zod

I have 2 enums, `const Option1 = z.enum(["option1"])` and `const Option2 = z.enum(["option2"])`.
I want to merge these two into `z.ZodEnum<["option1", "option2"]>`

The only way I came up with so far is

```
export const Options = z.enum([
  ...Option1.options,
  ...Option2.options,
]);
// Options.options is now ["option1", "option2"]
```

Is there any zod native way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue you're facing here is due to the type of the combined options.

```js
const allOptions = [...Option1.options, ...Option2.options]
```

the inferred type of `allOptions` in this case is: `("option1" | "option2")[]` and zod can't create an enum out of that.

however, if you define `allOptions` like this:

```js
const allOptions = [...Option1.options, ...Option2.options] as const
```

then the inferred type of `allOptions` will be the tuple `["option1", "option2"]` which is exactly what you want.

so, putting that all together, to combine the options, you'd say:

```js
const Options = z.enum([...Option1.options, ...Option2.options] as const)
```

and the inferred type of Options will be `z.ZodEnum<["option1", "option2"]>`